# When should I use angular.component instead of angular.directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

**Angular1.5** provides us the new concept - [**Component**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), like an improvement for old **element-directive** one.

It would be nice to have clear distinction between them: when to use what.

There is explanation on official site for cases when we should use directive. But all could be covered by attribute-directive. Is there still place left for element-directive in new applications?

Comment: Isn't it clearly stated in first paragraph on the link you provided? Component is for easy and quick directives definition, if you need DOM manipulations or extra configuration you use directive

Comment: Maybe this could help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244202/components-and-directives-in-angular-1-5

Comment: thank you! useful piece of information

Answer (score 0):

**Differences between .component() and .directive()**

Angular's Team release the last version for helping developers to migrate to Angular 2.

One of the implementation that helps is the .component() method. In fact in Angular 2 we talk much more about Components instead Directives.

Think about components like a small reusable thing that you can declare one time and share in all your applications.

The new .component() method is really similar the old .directive() but introduce some little differences that helps to adopt best practice. For example the link function is missing and you need to use a controller instead.

In this very helpful article by Aviv Ben-Yosef you can read more about the differences between .component() and .directive().

http://www.codelord.net/2015/12/17/angulars-component-what-is-it-good-for/

**When To Use**

If you want to migrate to Angular 2, use the .component(). So you can learn a very similar syntax to the new version and migrate very easily.

Answer (score 0):

In short, use directives only when you need to manipulate the DOM elements and in other cases use components.

Yes you can use directive as element if your requirement requires it.